# need help in PHP number format

Tags: php, number-formatting

Hello everyone i am trying to format the input number range with php number_format

### INPUT Probability

1. 1234
2. 12345
3. 123456789
4. 123456789,50
5. 123.45,00
6. 123.456.78,50

### OUTPUT should be

dot should be in multiplier of 3 digit and last two (if available in input range) digits should be come with comma separater

1. 1.234,00
2. 12.345,00
3. 123.456.789,00
4. 123.456.789,50
5. 12.345,00
6. 12.345.678,50

out put should be as per dutch format and dot should be in multiplier of 3 digit and last two digits should be come with comma separater

like, here is link you can [put any input value from above list in textbox](http://www.schulden-insolvenzberatung.de/wissenswertes/pfaendungsrechner/)  you can get output like shown below

the code which i am using

```
echo numberFormat('12345');

function numberFormat($num)
{
     return preg_replace("/(?<=\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/",".",$num);
}
```

but it will not work with (4),(5),(6) from my input probability to match with outputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I think is like this:

```
$number = 1234.56
echo number_format($number, 2, ',', '.');
```

About the input yo could check and all the "." remove it and the "," replace with "."

```
$number = "123.456,78";
$temp = str_replace(".", "", $number);
$temp2 = str_replace(",", ".", $temp);
echo number_format($temp2, 2, ',', '.');
```

I hope it helps

Comment: hi Ernesto,Thanks for the answer but i tried you code using a function numberformat($number) { $temp = str_replace(".", "", $number);
$temp2 = str_replace(",", ".", $temp);
return number_format($temp2, 2, ',', '.');
} where $number = 1.234,00  i am getting this error "a non well formed numeric value encountered" can you please help,

Comment: Oks then add before "echo number_format($temp2, 2, ',', '.');".

Add $temp2 = $temp2 * 1;
so you change it to numeric type

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty similar to @Emesto solution, but forced into a number:

```
$num = '123.456.789,50';
$n = str_replace('.', '', $num);
$n = str_replace(',', '.', $n);

# $n is no longer a string
$n = $n + 0;

# so it should work fine in number_format
echo number_format($n,2,',','.');
```

PS: I just tested this code to be sure that it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
number_format($input,2,',','.');
```

That should do it.

Comment: i tried it but if my input is like (4) and (5) from input probability then?

Comment: First `explode` on `,` - if the result has one element, go ahead and `number_format` it. If it has two elements, and the last element has two digits, do `$e[0]+$e[1]/100` (`$e` being the exploded elements) and `number_format` it. In all other cases, input is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

```
$temp=number_format((float)$number, 2, '.', '');

$inter =number_format($temp,2);

$temp1=str_replace(',','.',$inter);
$final=substr_replace($temp1,',',-3,1);

echo"$final";
```

Hope it helps